# Reading HTTP Request custom Headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on ASP.NET MVC 2 application. the website runs under SiteMinder (3rd party agent) for authentication. The Siteminder injects custom header to the incoming HTTP request.  But when I try to read the custom header, I donot get the value.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["CustomKey"];
```

Looks like these custom headers are getting stripped by MVC. I hav eensured that the headers are for sure getting injected by SiteMinder.

Am I doing anything wrong while reading as shown above?

Answer (score 13):

You're looking for `HttpRequest.Headers`, not `ServerVariables` which represent variables served by IIS to the application:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["CustomKey"];
```

Comment: I tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["CustomKey"]; as well as System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["CustomKey"];  Both did not work

Comment: @MeghanaK did you ever figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You you tried using Fiddler Http Proxy agent to verify that custom headers is injected by siteminder in the response header.??